# How can I access files using Sheets or Excel Online from Dropbox when it's blocked by my organization?

Tags: google-sheets, dropbox, excel-online

I have a Dropbox account which has a few Microsoft Excel files that I want to edit from work.

My organization has disabled Dropbox access and, as a result, I can't access the files from work.

I don't want to have to copy the files from Dropbox to Google Drive or Microsoft OneDrive to be able to view/edit/save them while at work.

Is it possible to leave the files in DropBox but be able to view/edit/save the files while at work using either Excel Online or Google Sheets?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more clarity.  It isn't clear what it means that ***"My org has disabled Dropbox"*** Right now the question reads kind of like "I can't access Dropbox at work. Can I access Dropbox at work?"  You can move your file(s) to a cloud host that your org allows. It isn't clear what the problem is with the obvious simple solution or what kind of parameters you have for an acceptable solution if the simple obvious one isn't acceptable. Also, What you have tried? What do you experience?